# Post build script to copy all the files from different to output directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, post-build-event

I want to copy multiple files from different folders which are inside my project directory to my output directory using post build command. Is there a way by using a post build command to copy all the files from these different folders to my bin\debug folder. I used xcopy with the switches /s. But it did not work

```
Folder1
 File1
 File2
Folder2
 File3
 File4
FOlder3
 File5
 File6

Output
..\bin\debg
   File1
   File2
   File3
   File4
   File5
   File6
```

Comment: What did you try? Could you post the command you tried?

Comment: Do you solve the issue with my solution?

Comment: How about the new solution? Does it meet your requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this command to achieve your requirement:

```
xcopy /Y /I /E "$(ProjectDir)ParentFolder\*.*" "$(TargetDir)ParentFolder"
```

Update:

Copy files to a single folder (simple code):

```
if not exist "$(TargetDir)LibTest" mkdir $(TargetDir)LibTest 
pushd $(ProjectDir)LibTest
   for /r %%a in (*.*) do (
     copy "%%a" "$(TargetDir)LibTest"
   )
   popd
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This copies all the files with the folder structure.I want only the files to be moved.

Comment: @DotNetLearner Do you the files in children folders are need to be copied to a single folder?

Comment: As shown in my question above, I want only the files from all the folders to be moved to the output folder.

Comment: The updated version works for me with slight modifications. Thanks